# How can I remove chrome os entirely install Ubuntu on a Chromebook (Acer Chromebook CB315-3h)?

Tags: system-installation, chromebook, chromeos

I was wondering how I can install Ubuntu on a Chromebook (Acer Chromebook CB315-3h). I don't want the crouton chroot. I want to remove Chrome Os entirely, and install Ubuntu. Currently I'm trying to use `flashrom` to disable WP, but I get and error saying that it won't work most likely because of an active ME.

After I run the command `chromeos-firmwareupdate --mode=todev crossystem dev_boot_usb=1` I get an error: `bash: chromeos-firmwareupdate: command not found`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a Chromebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302827/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-chromebook)

Comment: Not sure if you can totally remove Chrome OS. But you can certainly install a full blown Ubuntu on your chromebook. Try these links: [How to Install Linux on a Chromebook and Unlock Its Full Potential](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343) [How to Easily Install Ubuntu on Chromebook with Crouton | Linux.com | The source for Linux information](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-easily-install-Ubuntu-Chromebook-crouton)

Comment: @24601 when I run the command `chromeos-firmwareupdate --mode=todev crossystem dev_boot_usb=1` I get an error: `bash: chromeos-firmwareupdate: command not found`